# Progress bar and text are not aligned

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to align the text to the side of the progress bar. but the text and the progress bar in the container are not being aligned. How do I align them side by side? I have provided the html code and the screenshot of the problem below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container" style="height: 250px;">
                <h3>Operating Systems</h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">Ubuntu</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="progress" style="height: max-content;">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-animated progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%"
                                aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><strong>75%</strong></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

[Progress bar and their label are not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuNMe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Md. Shajedul Hasan

Here is the answer

User md instead of xs

```css
.someSpace{
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container" style="height: 250px;">
                    <h3>Operating Systems</h3>
      <div class="someSpace"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1">Ubuntu</div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="progress" style="height: max-content;">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-animated progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%"
                                    aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><strong>75%</strong></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1">Ubuntu Fedora</div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="progress" style="height: max-content;">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-animated progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%"
                                    aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><strong>75%</strong></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: or visit : https://codepen.io/parth-mehta-the-vuer/pen/gOaVpmy
Please watch in full page : https://prnt.sc/sq86yp